# jquery and hiding floated divs

Tags: jquery, html

Im running into a problem that I actually got working the last time I was working on the site im currently working on. But Im redesigning to incorporate other elements, and I cant seem to get the jquery part to work.

basically, I have an html document with divs. these divs have id=""s attached to them so that i can call them using jquery. basically what i want to do is show and hide divs that are part of one html document. these divs are floated one after another, but i need them to be shown at different times when a user clicks within the navigation.
below is the simplified markup i have in place, where the ids would be the tags to determine which one to hide and which to show, and the selectors would be in the individual list tags i have in the linkbar portion.

```
<body>
 <div class="linkbar"></div>
   <div class="pages">
   <div class="page-one" id="B1"></div>
   <div class="page-two" id="B2"></div>
   <div class="page-three" id="B3"></div> 
   <div class="page-four" id="B4"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

another note. almost all of these elements are floated within a 1000px width. the pages part is a 1000px width x "X" height space that I want filled with the page-one div's content.

below is the jQuery markup I have put into to display the first one on a page load, and then the subsequent ones after that to show and hide according to the "page" selected from the naivigation. the #A1-3 are the selectors associated with the navigation links.

```
$(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
    ${"B0").show();
    $("div.home").show();
    $("div.my-life").hide();
    $("div.photos").hide();
    $("div.video").hide();
    $("div.news").hide();
    $("div.contact-me").hide(); 
});
});


$(function() {
$("#A1").click(function() {
$("#B1").show();
$("#B2").hide();
$("#B3").hide();
$("#B4").hide();    
$("#B5").hide();
$("#B6").hide();    
});
});
$(function() {
$("#A2").click(function() {
$("#B1").hide();
$("#B2").show();
$("#B3").hide();
$("#B4").hide();    
$("#B5").hide();
$("#B6").hide();    
});
});
$(function() {
$("#A3").click(function() {
$("#B1").hide();
$("#B2").hide();
$("#B3").show();
$("#B4").hide();    
$("#B5").hide();
$("#B6").hide();    
});
});
```

Help? its driving me nuts, because this worked last time.

Comment: ${"B0").show();
the { should be a (

Comment: Hiya, ${"B0").show(); == $("#B0").show(); -- and I cannot see your B0 element in html either; looking into your code and might flick you jsfiddle soon, Can flick me all the html you got: of update in here http://jsfiddle.net/6nar4/50/ ; cheers!

Comment: Could be as simple as that typo. ;-) When working on JavaScript, having Chrome's Developer Tools (f12) or Firebug (a Firefox extension) opened to the Console tab will reveal problems like this. Side note: you can do all your hides and shows grouped together. Either cache them to an array of objects or even at least lump them together like this: `$('#B1, #B2, #B3').hide()`

Comment: you also don't need the "$(function() {" (and the corresponding "});"  lines. Not wrong I don't think, but not needed

Comment: Actually, It didnt work before I put that one in, and I changed it and it had no affect, so thats not it. currently I cant get it to hide any of the other divs when I put stuff in them. they just float beneath the "page-one" div.

Comment: Also, forgive me if my code isn't the cleanliest. I'm slowly teaching myself jQuery through trial and error and practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have a { instead of ( in your first selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //${"B0").show();
    $("B0").show();
    $("div.home").show();
    $("div.my-life").hide();
    $("div.photos").hide();
    $("div.video").hide();
    $("div.news").hide();
    $("div.contact-me").hide(); 
});
```

**Edit:**

Minor javascript errors such as this can easily be found using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), a extremely useful javascript debugger and general web development tool for Firefox.

By the way `$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` do the exact same thing and there is no need to use them more than once. You can include all of your jQuery within one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Function siblings can help you to optimize your code:

```
<body>
 <div class="linkbar">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link" rel="B1">B1</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link" rel="B2">B2</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link" rel="B3">B3</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link" rel="B4">B4</a>
    </div>
   <div class="pages">
   <div class="page-one" id="B1">b1</div>
   <div class="page-two" id="B2">b2</div>
   <div class="page-three" id="B3">b3</div> 
   <div class="page-four" id="B4">b4</div>
  </div>
 <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

​javascript:

```
​$('.link').click(function(){
    $('.pages').find('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).show().siblings().hide();
});​​​​​​
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZ7y9/10/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have way to many repetitive patterns in your original code. Try adhering to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle to help keep your code manageable. That said, I refactored your code to show how it could be simplified. [try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/82j5F/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('rel'); // grab rel attribute
        $('.pages').each(function() { // iterate
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {  // returns true if visible
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        $('.' + page).stop(true, true).toggle('slow'); // show page
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="linkbar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" rel="page-one">Page One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="page-two">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="page-three">Page Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="page-four">Page Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="pageWrapper">
    <div class="page-one pages">One</div>
    <div class="page-two pages">Two</div>
    <div class="page-three pages">Three</div>
    <div class="page-four pages">Four</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
.pages {
    display: none;
}
```